# error opening the storyboard files

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6, nsbundle

in my project i have different Storyboard files to support different iPhones, i have this code in my appDelegate:

```
if (window.frame.size.height == 568){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMain5Name bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    id rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
} else if (window.frame.size.height == 480){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMain5Name bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    id rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
} else if (window.frame.size.height == 667){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMain6Name bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    id rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
} else if (window.frame.size.height == 736){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMain6plusName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    id rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
}
```

every time i compile and run the app crashes saying it could not find storyboard file in NSBundle, i tied commenting out the above code and it worked again. is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Why don't you show us the names and then also a screenshot of project navigator with those storyboards?
If it says can't find them ..then maybe you have a wrong name or two.

Comment: ditto, we'll need to know if `kMain5Name` is actually in your project. The error suggests that it or it's companions are not in your project.

Comment: Somewhat related, you may want to simply use auto layout and size classes to handle the different device sizes. Is there a reason you don't use these tools?

Comment: @RodericCampbell i took the code from a previous project (targeted for iOS 7) and for some reason i do not remember i disabled auto layout in the previous project and so i did in this project (size classes are automatically disabled when auto layout is) kMain5Name is a macro (#define) with the file name.

Comment: @EarlGrey i have the exact names (i copied and pasted the file names into a macro (#define).. And i can't post pictures yet (low reputation)

Comment: Show us the macro then.

Comment: @EarlGrey #define kMain5Name @"Main5.storyboard"

Comment: @EarlGrey same thing goes for the rest but i changed the iPhone name (remove the k, replace name with .storyboard and you got the file name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from UIStoryboard Class reference

Parameters
name
The name of the storyboard resource file **without the filename extension.** This method raises an exception if this parameter is nil.

I made the relevant part bold. In case you are not a native speaker, it means do not add the extension into the parameter. But you did exactly that in your macro.

You really should read the documentation before trying to find some more esoteric cause for any problems in code.

Comment: Class reference documentation is the bible for any software development.

Comment: I will read every class reference from now on, thanks for the tip.